# Scrollbar manipulation using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to move scroll bar of a webpage up and down using selenium java? I have a webpage which has scroll bar in right which is used to move page up and down.

I want to test if it is working as expected. How should I proceed about it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could find an element, like the `body`, and after that send the key you need, page_up, page_down, end or up:

```
webElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//body"));
elem.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_UP);
elem.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight*0.5)");
```

Will scroll you to the middle of the page.